# Inserting data with relations into Strongloop application

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a Strongloop application using MongoDB. I have a model with several sub-models, using relations. When I try and insert an object into the database, only the top level data is added. All the related data is ignored. How do I get an entire object with sub-objects into the database?

Comment: Not the downvoter, and not sure why... but can you add some sample code for us to see what you're doing? Specifically I'd need to see the config json files for that model and the data you're sending into the api.

Answer (score -1):

See the embedded models documentation: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Embedded+models+and+relations